# SolrJ connect to Solr from Java

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm trying to connect from my Java code to a Solr server running 5.3.1 using the same version of SolrJ. I keep getting a message in Eclipse that HttpSolrServer is deprecated, but cannot find anywhere what it has been replaced with. Does anyone know how I can connect to Solr from Java using SolrJ using something current?  The SolrJ documentation all seems to suggest that HttpSolrServer is the supported way, but Eclipse is not happy about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse marks every class that has `@Deprecated` annotation as deprecated.
`HttpSolrServer` was deprecated indeed and [HttpSolrClient](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient.html) is its replacment

SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrLocation).build();

Comment: Hi, I have to connect to a https Solr server, I have the keystore file for that, can anyone tell how to add those properties while creating the solrClient?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Solr 6.1 this the preferred way with to create SolrJ HTTP client:

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/my-collection";
SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
```

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_5_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient.Builder.html

Answer (score 0):

public class SolrCient {

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SolrCient.class.getName());

private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8983/solr/suggest";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SolrServerException {

    HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient(SERVER_URL);

    QueryResponse  response = solr.query(new SolrQuery("*:*"));

    System.out.println(response.toString());

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

deprecated:

SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient(solrLocation);

use this:

SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrLocation).build();